# How to compile my bibliography which gives a very bad error

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am doing a projet for my Bachelor in Mathematics course.
However, I am stuck on how to cite the following paper in my Latex code:

The BiB file of the paper is given as follows:

```
@article{banerjee2022laplacian,
  title={Laplacian spectrum of comaximal graph of the ring ℤn},
  author={Banerjee, Subarsha},
  journal={Special Matrices},
  volume={10},
  number={1},
  pages={285--298},
  year={2022},
  publisher={De Gruyter Open Access}
}
```

I have the following code which consists of  a TeX file and also my References file iin the same folder. However, when I am compiling the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
    In  \cite{banerjee2022laplacian}, the authors have shown that 
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ℤ (U+2124)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end
```

Can someone please help me how to get rid of it?
This is my first project in my BSc. course, so I am not aware how to fix these type of errors.
I am looking forward from all the learned people out here for some help.

Comment: you could declare ℤ to work but it would be more normal to use tex markup in the bib file so `$\mathbb{Z}_n$` not `ℤn`

Comment: I used $\mathbb{Z}_n$ but I am not getting the desired output, can you pls give an alternative way and show it in an example by giving an answer, Sir

Comment: tha should work, you may need to delete your exising generated bbl file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; wow, deleting the bbl file worked, you are truly a genius, lots of love to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use math markup in the bib file:

```
  title={Laplacian spectrum of comaximal graph of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$},
```

Then delete your existing genrated `.bbl` file and re-run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex and get the output

[image]